# Warning in Avro Schema definition

Tags: java, avro

I got a warning for a defined field:

```
Ignored the logicalType property ("timestamp-millis"). It should probably be nested inside the "type" for the field.

{"name": "leaving", "type": ["null" ,"long"], "logicalType": "timestamp-millis", "default": null, "doc": "leaving timestamp"}
```

I tried to change it to:

```
{"name": "leaving", "type": {"type": ["null" ,{"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}]}, "doc": "leaving timestamp"}
```

now it doesn't work at all because of invalid schema.

Error:

```
InvocationTargetException: No type: {"type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]}
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `type` duplicated. It should be

```
{
  "name": "leaving",
  "type": ["null" , {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}],
  "doc": "leaving timestamp"
}
```